# ash - parse a config file line after line

Tags: ash

My config file looks as follows:

```
ver 3
file test1.conf ~/etc
file test2.conf ~/etc/conf
script tst.sh
```

I'd like my script to iterate through all lines prefixed with "file", extract filename and location values and execute some operation. Since now I got:

```
files=$(cat file.conf | grep file)
```

But then I'm not sure how to get into iteration to extract second and third string out of each line.

Comment: `ash` is POSIX Shell compatible, and `bash` contains many extensions, but you might get some ideas in https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: If you need something as complicated as reading a config file, that is a strong indication that you should be using a proper programming/scripting language and not the shell. Do you _have_ to use a shell for this? Can't you use perl or python or anything else?

Comment: No I cannot, because it is simple linux on the router. But I managed to solve it using read and awk.

Comment: @Kal800 You can write an answer for your own question.

Answer (score 0):

Just like you would do with any POSIX shell:

```
while read type name path; do
  if [ "$type" = file ]; then
    echo "$path/$name";
  fi
done < your.conf
```

Use `read` to split your lines into variables, test for the first varible to be `file` and do what you want to do with the other elements. You don't need `awk` or the like for this.